# After get the values from sql in datatable  i need to convert byte[] to image and need to add in datatable after that view in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to view values from the database in a DataGrid.  I have a column called signature, which contains images stored as byte arrays.  However, I don't know how to view these images in the DataGrid.

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("CustomerInformations");
string Cn = "Data Source=\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Export;Integrated Security=true;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Cn);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Date],[CustomerName],[Amount],[Bank] ,[Signature] ,[IMEINumber] from PaymentReceipt where ReceiptID = 44", con);
sqlDa.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

this.dataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
```

There is a column called `signature` in the database.  Its datatype is `varbinary`.

Before I assigned the datatable to `datagrid1` I need to convert the signature(`byte[]`) to an image.

Here is my code for converting a `byte[]` to an image:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr[4];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

I don't know how to add the return image in the signature field in datatable.  Can you please help me?

Here is my XAML file

```xml
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Height="260" Width="705">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with AutoGenerate columns.  You need to bind the image column to a ValueConverter.   This converts from file to an image but it should get you started.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/ea1fd63b-738c-40ca-850e-994eb21dccea 
You may need a templated column to host an image viewer.